# Saving Excel File as HTML(Cell Formatting is not shown in converted HTML)

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to save Excel Sheet to HTML using Office Interope libraries. Everything works fine but formatted cells are not shown as they are in excel sheet. Here is how it looks in MS Excel

[image]

And here is what it looks like after conversion in HTML

[image]

Here is the code I am using to save  Excel sheet as HTML

```
xApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object missing = Type.Missing;
object trueObject = true;
xApp.Visible = false;
xApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xWorkBook = xApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath, missing, trueObject, missing,
 missing, missing,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
 missing, missing, missing);
object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
xWorkBook.SaveAs(tempFileName, format, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                                       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
missing, missing, missing,missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell formatting shouldn't be visible on the paper or HTML pages. Try to print the page.

If you need to see the cells printed or visible on the HTML page, set the [Borders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Range class:

```
Sub SetRangeBorder()  
  With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous 
    .Weight = xlThin 
    .ColorIndex = 3 
  End With  
End Sub
```